# MapTiler plugin layer: No such file or directory error message

Tags: qgis, raster, error, hillshade, maptiler

I'm trying to create a Hillshade layer in QGIS using the Terrain RGB layer from the MapTiler plugin. When I run the raster hillshade function, I get the below error. I'm probably missing something obvious.

```
    GDAL command:
    gdaldem hillshade "type=xyz&url=https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?usage={usage}&authcfg=d764y16&interpretation=maptilerterrain&zmax=12" /private/var/folders/7v/3ttbbmtn44332qv9gztjrqy00000gn/T/processing_sgCrFc/f81e29f96c7642dab7546e720da1cb64/OUTPUT.tif -of GTiff -b 1 -z 1.0 -s 1.0 -az 315.0 -alt 45.0
    
    GDAL command output:
    ERROR 4: type=xyz&url=https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?usage={usage}&authcfg=d764y16&interpretation=maptilerterrain&zmax=12: No such file or directory
    GDALOpen failed - 4
    type=xyz&url=https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?usage={usage}&authcfg=d764y16&interpretation=maptilerterrain&zmax=12: No such file or directory
    Process returned error code 1
```

Comment: That something you're missing is that the XYZ tile layer you're trying to use isn't a DEM, it's a rendered image.  You probably need to export your area of interest to a geotiff, then generate a DEM by calculating elevation per the [maptiler docs](https://cloud.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-rgb/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should GDAL translate not convert the layer for me? If not, how would you recommend I export the area of interest to a geotiff as when I go to Export > Save As, then save as a geotiff, a VRT file is created which I can't open in QGIS.